# Installation via USB drive

Tags: usb

I recently downloaded version 12.10 to a flash drive.  When I try to load it, it does not go to a setup or installation page.  Goes to a log-in page, and asks for a username and password that I haven't established yet.  Is there a way to get past this page?

Comment: Try take out you're USB stick then reboot, if logon screen comes up then it's probably installed. *edit* You mean logon screen on win is coming up or ubuntu? After you get you're iso file on the USB and reboot you're pc, then it should pop up a screen that says "run ubuntu" or "install ubuntu" etc , you did see that and done that yeah?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you already installed. Try to boot directly from USB drive and not from the harddisk.

Comment: No...old operating system still on hard drive.  New one boots only from usb, but goes to log-in page.  Dead end.